# Is it possible to make Spinner invisible? Xamarin.Android

Tags: c#, oop, xamarin

Hi I have some C# code for the Windows CE app that I'm now making into an Android app with Xamarin..
Is this possible to do with Xamarin spinner? I haven't been able to find an answer to this.. Thanks.

```
cbSubject.Visible = false;
```

Comment: Does my solution work for you? If yes, can you please accept it (click the ☑️ in the upper left corner of this answer ) so that we can help more people with same problem:).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In code behind:

```
 Spinner s = new Spinner(context: this);
 s.Visibility = ViewStates.Visible;
 s.Visibility = ViewStates.Invisible;
```

In xml:

```
 android:visibility="invisible"
 android:visibility="visible"
```

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution. If ever somebody needs this it is:
myView = ViewStates.[Invisible/ Visible/ Gone].